# Linux unset my ip adress

Tags: linux, ip

It seems that my Ubuntu 14 keeps deleting the IP adress of my eth0.

Has anyone else seen this happen before? 
Where should I begin checking?

I have no log to show : after setting the address with `ifconfig eth0 10.10.0.4 netmask 255.0.0.0` the IP is visible in ifconfig, but disappears after a few minutes.

EDIT :

```
$ dmesg | grep eth0
[    5.293971] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM95723) rev 5784100] (PCI Express) MAC address 3c:4a:92:b2:a2:1e
[    5.293974] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5784 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[0])
[    5.293976] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[    5.293978] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
[    9.124499] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   10.758438] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   10.758756] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   13.183081] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   13.183091] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[   13.183104] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Most likely, you have a network-manager running (name depends on distro), which runs a dhcp client. Even if you assign a static IP address manually, at some point the network manager will take over and restore the DHCP-assigned address. If you want to do it on the fly, then you have to disable the network-manager somehow (you can also disable it only for eth0) and **then** assign a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set it in the /etc/network/interfaces file

The format is like this for a static IP:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.10.0.4
  netmask 255.0.0.0
  gateway 10.10.0.1
  broadcast 10.255.255.255
  network 10.0.0.0
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
  dns-search domain-search.com
```

If you want dhcp:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

After that, save the file and restart your networking:
/etc/init.d/networking restart (I believe this is the old way to do it, but should work).

Comment: @romain The point here is that the dhcp client is always running if the interface is set to dhcp.  So setting it manually to something will get overwritten by the dhcp client.

Comment: The above works in Debian and derivatives, perhaps the OPer  has a different distro.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Correct me if I'm wrong but OP listed Ubuntu 14 as their distro, which is a variant of Debian